# Translating "deploy" and "deployment"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

How would you translate *deploy / deployment* into Spanish?

I guess that these would be possible translations for *deploy*, but maybe there is a better term?

- **poner en funcionamiento**
- **será instalado**

Examples:

> The new software will be deployed later this week.
>    The application will be deployed to several servers.
>    Our deployment plan consists of three steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best translation is "desplegar" or "implementar" if you are talking about a "progressive" set-up, but your translations also sound good to me.

Answer (score 7):

"Deploy" and "deployment" are almost always translated as ***desplegar*** and ***despliegue***.

Your examples translated:

> The new software will be deployed later this week. → *El nuevo* software *será desplegado a finales de esta semana.*
>   The application will be deployed to several servers. → *La aplicación será desplegada en varios servidores.*
>   Our deployment plan consists of three steps. → *Nuestro plan de despliegue consiste en tres pasos.*

As an authoritative reference (kinda), compare the IBM manuals for WebSphere deployment in English: [Deploying and starting WebSphere Application Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYMRC_5.0.2/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/c_deploying_was.html) and Spanish: [Despliegue e inicio de WebSphere Application Server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSYMRC_5.0.2/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/c_deploying_was.html). The same goes for Microsoft, Oracle, Apache, what have you.